# openpyxl data_only gives only a none answer when storing a variable

Tags: openpyxl

So basically what I am trying to do is read in some input variables from an excel workbook and write them into some Output Model cells. Then I save the workbook to try to update the data in the Output Model. Since my Output Model cells are formulas I try to reload the workbook as a read data_only and then grab those cells and store them on a separate sheet. Then I save the workbook one more time.

The problem is the values I try to grab (LS, Sales, TPLH) in the data_only loaded workbook reads out as none instead of the values that I need. I eventually want to make this into a loop to iterate over a bunch of input variables, but I wanted to try it with just one set to begin with.

If anyone knows of a better way to do this or what I am doing wrong please let me know! I appreciate any and all feedback.
Here is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook("Z:\\PythonFiles\\testexcel.xlsx")
sh2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name("Output Model")
sh= wb2.get_sheet_by_name('OptimizationData')

ForeCast = sh.cell(row=3, column=2).value
sh2.cell(row=3, column=6).value=ForeCast
wb2.save("Z:\\PythonFiles\\testexcel.xlsx")

wb = load_workbook("Z:\\PythonFiles\\testexcel.xlsx", data_only =True)
sh3 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Output Model")
sh4 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("OptimizationData")

LS=sh3.cell(row=11, column=3).value
Sales = sh3.cell(row=12, column=3).value
TPLH = sh3.cell(row=13, column=3).value

sh4.cell(row=3, column=7).value=LS
sh4.cell(row=3, column=8).value=Sales
sh4.cell(row=3, column=9).value=TPLH

wb.save("Z:\\PythonFiles\\testexcel.xlsx")
```

Comment: Related but not 100% dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35681902/2988730

Answer (score 1):

Openpyxl will never calculate the result of a formula. It is entirely dependent upon another application having done that. It also means that such values are stripped from a workbook when it is passed through openpyxl. This happens as soon as you save `wb2`. If you want to access those values then you need to open `wb` in data-only mode first.