# How to copy-paste data from an OS-running application with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, process

I need to write an application that basically focuses on a given Windows window title and copy-pastes data in a notepad. I've managed to achieve it with pygetwindow and pyautogui, but it's buggy:

```
import pygetwindow as gw
import pyautogui


# extract all titles and filter to specific one
all_titles = gw.getAllTitles()
titles = [title for title in all_titles if 'title' in title]

window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(titles[0])[0].activate()

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
```

Using Spyder, I ocasionally get the following error when activating:

```
PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 126 - The specified module could not be found.
```

Additionally, I would be interested in doing this process without affecting the user working on the machine. Activate basically makes the window pop to front. Moreover, it would be better to not be OS dependant, but I haven't found anything yet.

I've tried pywinauto but the SetFocus() method doesn't work (it's buggy, documented).

Is there any other method which would make the whole process invisible and easier?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help

I am using pywinauto to set_focus

```
import pywinauto
import pygetwindow as gw
def focus_to_window(window_title=None):
    window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(window_title)[0]
    if not window.isActive:
        pywinauto.application.Application().connect(handle=window._hWnd).top_window().set_focus()
```