# Use data_only=True when you load your workbook. (For example, workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("yourxlsx.xlsx", data_only=True))

Tags: openpyxl

I am not able to print the computed cell value with this option. it is printing the formula instead of cell value.. can someone please help me on this.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

sheet['L3'] = '=COUNTIF(B1:B431,"Resolved")'

now I want to print the L3 cell value to the screen

Answer (score 0):

[Python openpyxl data_only=True returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116162/python-openpyxl-data-only-true-returning-none)

According the this thread, the formula needs to be evaluated by Excel before having its value cached.