# Can't access the cell which contains a formula in openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

It is said that argument `data_only=True` helps read data in cell from excel.
[image]
I want to get the value in cell `B10` which contains a simple formula,upload the data file in dropbox ,please download it and have a try with below codes:
[please download and have a try](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/954r4qmg40adkniynt8hb/valuation.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=xo09iw1nsbbhew7d3t0zlfik1)

```
dest_fn = "valuation.xlsx"
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(dest_fn, data_only=True)
ws = wb["valuation"]
print(ws['B10'].value)
#it shows nothing!
```

How can read the value in the cell then?
Are there  some other python lib which can read the value in cell containing a formula?

Comment: Openpyxl does not evaluate formulas, however it does have [some support](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html) that could help you to implement formula evaluation yourself

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/36116162/1328439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openpyxl can only read the value of a calculation if another application or library has performed the calculation and stored the value.

If you look at the source for this file it's clear that this has not happened:

```xml
    <x:c r="B10">
      <x:f>sum(B9:H9)</x:f>
      <x:v />
    </x:c>
```

This is why openpyxl returns `None` as the value. In fact, it looks like the file was probably created with openpyxl. Unfortunately, there is no magic. You'll need to open and then save the file in Excel or OpenOffice first.

Comment: Open and save the file , then i can read  value in  the cell.Is a bug for openpyxl?